# Relative time calculation

Tags: ruby, time

I have an application implementing RESTful API. I have two methods `create_order` and `order_status`. The first method creates order and persists it with the current time in the `order.time` field:

```
order.time = Time.now
```

The second method responds with a hardcoded value:

```
:eta => 20.minutes.from_now.to_i
```

Instead of returning the hardcoded 20 minutes, how can I return the relative value that decreases with elapsed time (depending on the time when status request was made)?

At the beginning of the order, they are the same (`20.minutes.from_now.to_i`), but if the request is made after 5 mins, it should be `15.minutes.from_now.to_i`.

Comment: Like `order.time + 20.minutes`?

Comment: @Stephat that would be a constant which is not depends on current time of request.

Comment: Let's say the beginning of the order is 12:00, ETA is calculated via `20.minutes.from_now`, which gives 12:20. Five minute later (it's 12:05), the ETA should be calculated via `15.minutes.from_now`, which gives 12:20. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Stephan yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save some other attribute along with `order.time`

For example : `order.eta = Time.now + 1200`

Or else : `order.processing_time = 1200` and then `order.eta` could be calculated.

I like the second solution better, enabling different processing times for different orders.